# CCBReader.h : No such file or director

Tags: error-handling, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to Do raywenderlich tutorial 'Introduction To CocosBuilder'

As mentioned in tutorial I added CCControlExtension class and CCBReader class
with follow the instruction “Create groups for any added folders” is selected and that “Copy items into destination group’s folder” is checked.

Both the Added folders Color Different From Other Folders in Navigation Area in Xcode

When I run this App Error "CCBReader.h : No such file or director"

What is the solution Please help Me....................

Comment: are they red? then the files are missing. Are they blue-grey-ish? Then you had the wrong checkboxes selected and created a folder reference.